# Pooling all six (2 optical fiber + 4 4g) internet connection at home

Tags: router, home-networking, wireless-access-point, dd-wrt, mesh-networking

We not good at networking, the word 'pooling' may be wrong, please correct me as required. Thanks.

As WFH is the new normal, we are planning to pool all our internet connections at home for better bandwidth and for fail over purposes.

We have 4 4G mobiles and 2 optical fiber connections.

Initially we thought of buying a dual WAN router to pool 2 optical fiber connections but as the uptime for both connections are not so great, so we thought it is better to include Mobile connections too.

We thought of using 4 old routers in WiFi client mode to connect with mobile's hotspot and then to main router's WAN via Ethernet.

But we are doubtful about the WiFi performance due multiple  mobile hotspots.
And we are not finding multi wan routers with 5 to 6 WAN ports and Wifi.

May be we need to separate wifi access points from the main router.

Please let us know your views/suggestions/recommendations. We wish to fix this internet problems at home once for all.

Comment: You might want to look into a decent box for pfsense/opensense. The only other things you will find are enterprise grade routers with these capabilities, and they will be pretty expensive! I can write something up for you if you want.